Various combination of model predictions yields to similar ground truth
I have a model(3DUnet, Regression problem) that predicts values PD and T1, where PD and T1 are the qMRI outputs based on the input. From these predictions, I calculate T1_Weighted_image using the formula: Weighted_images  = PD (1 - exp(-1 / (T1 + epsilon)))*, where epsilon is a small value to prevent division by zero and T1=>0 . During training, my ground truth for loss computation is T1_Weighted_groundtruth, but I also have ground truth values for PD and T1, although they are not directly used for loss computation. They serve to ensure the correctness of predicted values for PD and T1. The loss is computed using a loss function between T1_Weighted_predict and T1_Weighted_groundtruth.
However, there exist various combinations of PD or T1 that can yield similar results for T1_Weighted. For instance, instead of predicting high values for T1 (which is the correct answer), my model might predict very low values for PD (for example in CSF as an obvious example). Is there a method to compel my model to predict the correct values, or at least to predict (any) possible combinations?

You could implement it as a form of multi-output regression, where you ask both A and B to be predicted (see for example https://github.com/Project-MONAI/MONAI/discussions/3731)

Well currently my output is shaped as [C,D,H,W]. where C=0 is PD and C=1 is T1, but the question (as they have mentioned) is how to make different predictions? for instance one channel/head for PD is predicting low values for PD. How can the method be adjusted so that if we modify the network/method another PD head/channel is predicting high values? (similarly for T1 channel/head). and also loss computation might be tricky, as I do not care about when PD is predicted low instead of high.  (high and low values have abstract meanings just to give the idea of the problem)

How is this a programming problem? Its just a machine learning setup, so it is off-topic here.

Is there any correlation between PD and T1, if yes then you can atleast provide the model with there correlation information

Try penalizing PD and T1 separately as well. Account for their relative scales to each other and the combined metric. Or only use their loss, when the difference is over a threshold or the ratio between them is wrong.

I cannot use the ground truth values of T1 and PD during training but just for validation of the predictions. how can it be done then?
